# Error on checking Connectivity on Nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am checking internet connectivity in nativescript. I wrote the following code:

```
  startMonitoring(): void {
    connectivity.startMonitoring((newConnectionType: number) => {
      switch (newConnectionType) {
          case connectivity.connectionType.none:
              this.connectionType = "None";
              console.log("Connection type changed to none.");
              break;
          case connectivity.connectionType.wifi:
              this.connectionType = "Wi-Fi";
              console.log("Connection type changed to WiFi.");
              break;
          case connectivity.connectionType.mobile:
              this.connectionType = "Mobile";
              console.log("Connection type changed to mobile.");
              break;
          default:
              break;
      }
    });  
  }
```

and added permission on Android Manifiest like so:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Then when I run **tns debug android** I still got an error saying:

> JS: ERROR Error: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService:
>   Neither user 10224 nor current process has
>   android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE. JS:
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1954) JS:
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1900) JS:
>   android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:1216)
>   JS:
>   android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:903)
>   JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1203) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1083) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1070) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1050) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1042) JS:
>   com.tns.gen.android.content.BroadcastReceiver_vendor_119374_32_BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(BroadcastReceiver_vendor_119374_32_BroadcastReceiver.java:19)
>   JS:
>   android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDisp...

Its weird that I still got an error even though I added permission already. Why is this happening?

PS: Also tried **tns run android** but with same error.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try a clean build?

Comment: how exactly to do that? I tried uninstalling the app then run tns run android again. It still didnt work

Comment: Try [tns platform clean](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/project/configuration/platform-clean) or simply delete the `platforms` folder.

Comment: BTW, why does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a clean build.

Run [tns platform clean](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/project/configuration/platform-clean) Or simply delete the `platforms` folder then do `tns [run | debug]`

Comment: Whenever you change anything within `App_Resources` Or add any plugin / native dependencies, the native project has to be recompiled. Otherwise only the updated JavaScript code is shipped and app is refreshed. Most times CLI detects when you need a clean build and takes care of itself but sometimes it may fail, like your case then you have to perform a clean build manually to make sure the native project is updated with latest config changes.

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much!